# JavaScript: automatically updating the length property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, properties

This is not actually a jQuery question, but jQuery does something I would like to be able to do with other objects.

I notice that jQuery returns the number of elements using the `.length` property. However, the jQuery object is not actually an array, so the number of elements is not naturally available that way.

I presume that the jQuery object uses numbered keys for the actual elements, since `[n]` returns one of them.

How is it possible to have a `.length` property of a non-array automatically updated when elements are added or removed? Or is that manually maintained when jQuery adds or removes elements?

Thanks

Comment: It's not automatically updated - just try yourself to assign something to an index. jQuery (and the `Array` methods it uses) maintain it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've observed, a jQuery object is not actually an array.  Thus, the `.length` property is just maintained manually by any method that might actually change the internal contents of the array-like list of DOM objects.

This works fairly easily with a jQuery object because very few methods actually change the list of DOM objects in an existing jQuery object.  Most jQuery methods such as `.filter()` that operate on the list of DOM element in a jQuery object actually return a new jQuery object and the original jQuery object is not modified.

Even a jQuery method like `.add()` or `.slice()` do not modify the existing jQuery object, but instead return a new jQuery object with the appropriate modification in it.

If you trace through the jQuery source and look at how a lot of jQuery objects are created, pretty much all the methods that operate on a given jQuery object go through `.pushStack()` which calls `jQuery.merge()` which manually sets the `.length` property  on the new jQuery object.

If you look at the code for the main jQuery constructor `$(someSelector)`, it does some sort of document query, builds the internal array-like list of DOM nodes, then manually sets the `.length` property.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. As I said, I wasn’t really interested in the jQuery angle, but just whether there was a trick I wasn’t aware of. I now know a little more about the inner workings of jQuery, which will be helpful.

Comment: @Manngo - FYI, ES6 introduces the ability to actually subclass special types of objects like `Array` (which the spec calls "exotics").  So, if you want a custom object that works like an array and has the magic `.length` property`, you can subclass an Array in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

It’s manually maintained. Compare:

```
var l = [];
console.log(l.length); // 0
l[0] = 0;
console.log(l.length); // 1
```

```
var l = $([]);
console.log(l.length); // 0
l[0] = 0;
console.log(l.length); // 0
```